# Angular Google Maps mapClick() event not working

Tags: angular, maps, google-maps-markers

**Using Angular Google Map** (AGM), I'm trying to add a new marker when map is clicked. To do so, I have added an event *mapClick* that will send the event with the coordinates to *addMarker* method.

```
<agm-map [latitude]="location.latitude" [longitude]="location.longitude" (mapClick)="addMarker($event.coords.lat, $event.coords.lng)">
<agm-marker [latitude]="location.latitude" [longitude]="location.longitude"></agm-marker>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Location } from '../models/map-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  public location: Location;
  public markers: [];

  constructor() { /*empty*/ }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.location = {
      latitude: -28.68352,
      longitude: -147.20785
    }
  }

  addMarker(latitude: number, longitude: number) {
    console.log(`latitude: ${latitude}, longitude: ${longitude}`);
  }
}
```

**PROBLEM**:

- CANNOT GET COORDINATES. Error in html = 'Identifier coords is not defined'
- When i print the *event* on console, returns "c".

[image]

Comment: What version do you have installed? Check package.json.

Comment: I have installed the following versions: "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0" and "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.13" @hyperdrive

Comment: @hyperdrive Do I need another different version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1845) in the latest published version. `3.0.0-beta.0`

It's apparently been fixed but not published.

You could revert to `^1.1.0`.

Or implement the [workaround suggested in the issue](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1845#issuecomment-672051511).

Comment: That was the problem. I've changed the version to 1.1.0 and know it works. Thanks! @hyperdrive